# How do I create an extension for VS 2017 for new classifiers in the Fonts and Colors?

Tags: c#, syntax, colors, editor, vsix

I want to create a VSIX extension for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, for adding a group of new classifiers to the Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors, for the Text Editor. I would like an extension with classifiers for a range of different characters (in this case braces and other delimiters), to select individual colors for each specific character.

For example, I would like to choose a specific color for the pair of braces, the pair of parentheses, brackets, etc.

I have looked around and found a lot of tutorials about creating extensions of different kinds, but I don't seem to be able to find anything about this particular issue.

Anyone who can help with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a ClassificationFormatDefinition for your various classification types. I believe the OOK language integration sample has an example of this, located in the [VS Extensibility Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples) on GitHub.

Sincerely, 
Ed Dore

Comment: Hi Ed, I'll give it a try. Thank you very much for your help.